# default language value overrides translation field in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-modeltranslation

I am using Django model translation for the multi-linguistic site(English(default), Arabic, French), the problem is when saving data in django admin default overrides both Arabic and French translation fields. But in database actual value presents.

My Model:
plan/models.py

```
class operators(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    operator = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_('Operator Logo'), max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Operator'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Operators'
        db_table = 'operator'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.operator
```

plan/translation.py:

```
@register(operators)
class OperatorsTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('operator',)
```

plan/admin.py:

```
class OperatorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('operator', 'country')
.
.
.
admin.site.register(operators, OperatorAdmin)
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation',
.
.
.
'plan',

]
.
.
.
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('ar', gettext('Arabic')),
    ('fr', gettext('French')),

)
.
.
MODELTRANSLATION_TRANSLATION_FILES = (

    'plan.translation',


)
MODELTRANSLATION_DEBUG = True
```

Below is the database value

```
planbaker=# select * from operator;
 id |  operator  |         image         | country_id | operator_ar  | operator_en | operator_fr 
----+------------+-----------------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------
  1 | airtel-ind | pb_Zu2y9BE.jpeg       |          1 |              |             | 
  3 | aircel     | 360_360_1_vsXSDEo.JPG |          2 | ايرتل        | aircel      | 
  2 | aircel-sa  | 352_hQ4TZVq.jpeg      |          2 | زين السعودية | aircel-sa   | aircel-sa
```

But in Admin all the field have operator value only in english .
Can somebody please tell me where i went wrong? I tried both updte_translation_fields and sync_translation_fields but not helping

Answer (score 1):

Try using `modeltranslation.admin.TranslationAdmin` instead of `ModelAdmin` for your `OperatorAdmin` class.

> In order to be able to edit the translations via the django.contrib.admin application you need to register a special admin class for the translated models. The admin class must derive from modeltranslation.admin.TranslationAdmin which does some funky patching on all your models registered for translation.

https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html